# Netty cuts off received WebSocket message at 4096 bytes

Tags: websocket, client, netty

I have a WebSocket client in netty, and I receive a large frame from the server (~90kb). When doing this with OkHttp everything works, while receiving with netty (4.1.11.Final) the message always gets cut off at 4096 no matter my options.

Here is the code to setup the client:

```
SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().build();

final WebSocketClientHandler handler = getWebSocketClientHandler(WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(
                    uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, true, new DefaultHttpHeaders()),
                    this::messageHandler);

Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(eventLoopGroup)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, Math.toIntExact(connectionTimeout.toMillis()))
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port));

                            WebSocketClientExtensionHandler clientExtensionHandler = getWebSocketClientExtensionHandler();
                            List<ChannelHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>(4);
                            handlers.add(new HttpClientCodec(500_000, 504_000, 504_000, false, false, 504_000));
                            handlers.add(new HttpObjectAggregator(500_000));
                            handlers.add(handler);
                            handlers.add(WebSocketClientCompressionHandler.INSTANCE);
                            p.addLast(handlers.toArray(new ChannelHandler[handlers.size()]));
                        }
                    });
```

Am I forgetting something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebSocketClientHandler` is before the compression handler in the pipeline. If the server is sending you compressed messages, you're probably seeing smaller frame sizes (compared to the original, uncompressed message) in your handler. Put the compression handler before your `WebSocketClientHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but seems like the server did not send compressed data (changing the order or commenting out the compression handler did have no effect, it was still cut off at 4096 byes)